# Generating and distributing a secret without trusting the source

Tags: public-key, secret-sharing

I have multiple entities (servers) that all share a private secret already.
Those servers need a rotating secret (TTL a few hours). All servers must have the same set of secrets at all times.

I have another server (command & control) with a communication channel to all my clients.
I want the command & control to handle the generating and rotating of the temporary secrets.
I also don't want the command & control to ever know the temporary secret.

So basically:

- command & control generates a random blob
- command & control distributes the blob to clients
- clients use their shared secret to reduce the blob into a common secret (using I presume a pseudo-random cryptographic function)
- the final secret needs to be ~80 bytes

What would be the best practices to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a KBKDF on the clients, using the earlier secret as Input Keying Material (IKM) using the random as salt or `Info` input. KDF's generally have an output size parameter as well.

Currently HKDF is considered a good KDF, and if you use the full function it supports a salt.

Basically you would be implementing a so-called ratchet, where each key depends on the previous one, but doesn't provide any information about the previous keying material.